# Class cast exception in Ejb lookup

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, wildfly-8

I have a simple multimodule maven project with a war ejb and ear

When i am trying to access my ejb from a java pojo class using lookup it gives me class cast exception on wildfly it runs perfectly on jboss 7..

I have checked almost all the links related to this post please do help if anyone know how to resolve this..Here is my sample code:

My ejb interface:

```
package interfacejar;

import javax.ejb.Local;


public interface HelloWorldRemote {
       public String sayHello();       
       public void helloWait() ;  
}
```

Session Bean

```
@Stateless
public class HelloWorld implements Serializable, HelloWorldRemote {

    public String sayHello() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "hello";
    }

    public void helloWait(){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("in ejb");   
    }



}
```

My War Interface:
//As i am accessing ejb from pojo class which is in different module of my maven project so it requires to create interface here also in this module

```
package interfacejar;

public interface HelloWorldRemote {
       public String sayHello();  

       public void helloWait() throws Exception;  
}
```

My Java class

```
public class Testnew{




    public HelloWorldRemote getProps(){
        HelloWorldRemote ref=null;
         try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContextFactory");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url", "localhost");
        props.setProperty("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", "true");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");



            Context context = new InitialContext(props);

            Object obj =    context.lookup("java:global/MyEarFile/testejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld!interfacejar.HelloWorldRemote");

             ref=(HelloWorldRemote) obj;

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return ref;

    }




        public void getRemote(){
            HelloWorldRemote ref=null;
            try {
                ref=getProps();

                ref.helloWait();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }

}
```

Servlet that calls this class

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    this.processRequest(request, response);

}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.processRequest(request, response);
}
//java:global/MyEarFile/testejb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld!interfacejar.HelloWorldRemote*
/*@Resource(mappedName = "java:global/MyEarFile/tstwar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld!interfacejar.HelloWorldRemote")
private HelloWorldRemote helloWorldRemote;*/

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("in servlet");

    Testnew testnew = new Testnew();
    testnew.getRemote();


}
```

This is the error that i got

```
21:06:49,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) java.lang.ClassCastException: interfacejar.HelloWorldRemote$$$view4 cannot be cast to interfacejar.HelloWorldRemote

21:06:49,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)    at com.test.Testnew.getProps(Testnew.java:43)

21:06:49,205 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3)    at com.test.Testnew.getRemote(Testnew.java:59)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

It did worked when i changed the lookup from ejb to war

```
Context context = new InitialContext(props);

        Object obj =    context.lookup("java:global/MyEarFile/AllWar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/HelloWorld!interfacejar.HelloWorldRemote");

         ref=(HelloWorldRemote) obj;
```

Giving the name of the war in which the lookup is being done solved my problem... Hope it will help others too

Answer (score 1):

> As i am accessing ejb from pojo class which is in different module of my maven project so it requires to create interface here also in this module

This is a mistake, to be honest I don't know how it worked for you on JBoss. You can't just create a class and cast into it, you need to add that module with session beans as a dependency to your war module.

Two classes, beside the same package and name, need to be loaded with the same class loader in order to be treated as the same class.

Comment: i have added the dependency of ejb in the war

Comment: And you still get the ClassCastException? Did you delete your local HelloWorldRemote class?

Comment: yes i did removed that class from war and added dependency of ejb in war still its giving exception i dont knw why

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't seem to annotate your interface nor `@Local` nor `@Remote`. You can annotate your interface

```
@Remote
public interface HelloWorldRemote ...
```

or a bean

```
@Remote(HelloWorldRemote.class)
@Stateless
public class HelloWorld implements HelloWorldRemote ...
```